# Cable from broadband router to computer (cross-over or regular)

Tags: networking, broadband

I have a wireless broadband (WiMax) and I want to move my computer from where the IDU (In Door Unit) is to another location.  So my plan is to get a longer ethernet cable from the IDU to the computer and run the cable through the ceiling..

I plan on sending my wife to the shops to get the cable but I need to know if it is a cross-over cable or not.  Does anyone know the answer?

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, however, what is an in door unit? I have never heard this term before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Door Unit? :S

Anyway... If the router has more than one port on it, You only need a standard ethernet cable. A router typically has DHCP (along with many other items) and will work fine on its own.

If it has only one ethernet port , there is no 100% way to know, but if it is called router, it most likely will be capable of using a standard cable.

(I believe but not 100% sure) A quick way to check is to look at your IP settings, if you have a standard (10.x.x.x, 192.168.x.x, 172.16.x.x) it uses ethernet. If you have 169.x.x.x (auto-configured), there is a chance it could be cross over as there is no infrastructure. If you have manual settings, there is not really any way of knowing.

Answer (score 1):

A 'regular' or straigh through cable.  Generally crossover cables are used only to connect two computers  directly to each other (ie, network card to network card) with no switch/hub/device in between.

Assuming this "in door unit" you refer to (never heard the term before) is some sort of router or access point it has [at least] two ports*; one for the WAN (Internet access) and one for the LAN (inside your house network), the LAN port is a switch or hub port so you don't need any xover.

- neither port HAS to be physical - eg if your provider gets you internet over wireless then the antenna/txmitter is the WAN "port".